# What chemicals cause the burnt silicon / IC smell?

Tags: mosfet

I've had a power mosfet go bad on me before, and I'm sure as many of you can guess, I had to answer "whoaaaa, what did you explode in here today" question many times!

I was wondering, does anyone know specifically what kind of chemicals give the "burnt" smell that silicon devices give off when they light on fire / explode / go bad?

Comment: It's not the silicon.  That should oxidize and form essentially glass.  However everything else around it gets hot and a lot of those things are organic compounds that if you breath too much of them turn you into a newt or make your genitals fall off.  Have you checked lately?

Comment: It's burnt plastic. This is at most tangentially on-topic for this site.

Comment: Please keep open. It's tangential but an experience that everyone dealing with electronics should be aware of. I don't think it's burnt plastic as you get the same smell with ceramic packages.

Comment: One time I pried open a power mosfet that literally cracked open, and I got a whiff of some really nasty stuff. I've smelled burned plastic, and it was definitely not that. The smell was incredibly intense from just a TO-220 package.

Comment: It is the magic smoke. The smell of burnt fairy dust.

Comment: good question - I have often wondered the same thing ...

Comment: @Jason - Everyone dealing with electronics is aware of it, but that's enough.  We can't communicate the smell over the internet, and the source of the smell is irrelevant for this site.  It's been 24 hours, and we've gotten nothing but speculation.